# JS Slider is covering my navigation div -- not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

thanks in advance for your assistance!

http://www.littlestonegroup.org

Problem is pretty self explanatory -- I have implemented an awesome slider http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The only issue is that the slideshow seems to cover up the info on the page and I can't seem to figure out why. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like your navigation is both displayed inline and floating causing your slideshow to flow up, and over - you could correct this with a `clear:both` on the slideshow - this is the short answer. I'll follow up with something a little more indepth.

Comment: You could also float the slideshow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css property to `slideshow` class

```
display: inline-block;
```

This will fix it